# Instagram like grid and feed view animation in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a UI similar to a profile page in Instagram. There is a grid in Instagram and when you open a post, it animates by scaling from grid image and feed opens. As you scroll down the feed, it scrolls down and when you go back, you seamlessly snap back to the grid. How do i achieve that? My code so far.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  animation
//
//  Created by Rishabh Aryal on 25/03/2024.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 1), count: 3)
    @State var activeImage: String = ""
    @State var lastActive: String = ""
    @Namespace var namespace
    @Namespace var namespace1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 1) {
                        ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { index in
                            VStack {
                                if (activeImage == "image-\(index)") {
                                    Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3)*4)/3).clipped().matchedGeometryEffect(id: "iimage-\(index)", in: namespace)
                                } else {
                                    Image("image-\(index+1)")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3)*4)/3)
                                        .clipped()
                                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "iimage-\(index)", in: namespace)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3)*4)/3)
                            .id("image-\(index)")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.spring(duration: 0.2)) {
                                    activeImage = "image-\(index)"
                                }
                            }
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "main-" + "image-\(index)", in: namespace1)
                        }
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(lastActive, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
            if activeImage != "" {
                VStack {
                    CustomBackNavBar(title: "All Posts") {
                        withAnimation(.spring(duration: 0.2)) {
                            lastActive = activeImage
                            activeImage = ""
                        }
                   }
                               
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVStack {
                                ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { index in
                                    if (activeImage == "image-\(index)") {
                                        Image("image-\(index+1)")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFill()
                                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 4 / 3)
                                            .clipped()
                                            .id("image-\(index)")
                                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "iimage-\(index)", in: namespace)
                                    } else {
                                        Image("image-\(index+1)")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFill()
                                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 4 / 3)
                                            .clipped()
                                            .id("image-\(index)")
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                activeImage = "image-\(index)"
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "main-" + activeImage, in: namespace1)
                        .onAppear {
                            proxy.scrollTo(activeImage, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.black)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    struct CustomBackNavBar: View {
        let title: String
        let backAction: () -> Void
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Button(action: backAction) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left") // SF Symbol for back arrow
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Back")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(title)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.systemBackground)) // Or any other color
            .shadow(radius: 2)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Have shared the code, let me know what I am doing wrong(mostly everything I guess?).